# Pandas - DataFrame reindex function returns a warning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Whats wrong with the code?:
Its returning a warning :

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2515
>       return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all()) FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will
>   perform elementwise comparison

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data1 = {'State':['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],'Year':[2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],'POP':[1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}

Frame4 =pd.DataFrame(Data1)
print('\n')
print Frame4

Frame5 = Frame4.reindex(['a','b','c','d','e'])
print Frame5

my o/p
 POP   State  Year
0  1.5    Ohio  2000
1  1.7    Ohio  2001
2  3.6    Ohio  2002
3  2.4  Nevada  2001
4  2.9  Nevada  2002

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2515
    return bool(asarray(a1 == a2).all())
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
   POP State  Year
a  NaN   NaN   NaN
b  NaN   NaN   NaN
c  NaN   NaN   NaN
d  NaN   NaN   NaN
e  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) instead of [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) as you are trying to change the *names* of the index axis.

```
Frame5 = Frame4.rename({0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4:'e'})
print(Frame5)
   POP   State  Year
a  1.5    Ohio  2000
b  1.7    Ohio  2001
c  3.6    Ohio  2002
d  2.4  Nevada  2001
e  2.9  Nevada  2002
```

The purpose of applying `reindex` is to align the indices of the dataframe in the new index selection logic.

By default, values in the new index that do not have corresponding records in the dataframe are assigned `NaN`.

Hence, when you specified the new index logic as `list('abcde')`, it checked all the index values but couldn't find a match as the prior indices had been in `range(0,4)`. So, it returned `Nans`instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Frame4 =pd.DataFrame(Data1)
print('\n')
print Frame4

Frame4.index = ['a','b','c','d','e']
print Frame4


   POP   State  Year
0  1.5    Ohio  2000
1  1.7    Ohio  2001
2  3.6    Ohio  2002
3  2.4  Nevada  2001
4  2.9  Nevada  2002


   POP   State  Year
a  1.5    Ohio  2000
b  1.7    Ohio  2001
c  3.6    Ohio  2002
d  2.4  Nevada  2001
e  2.9  Nevada  2002
```